# What is the difference between the 2 forms of C assignments

Tags: c

I have 2 forms which actually output different results which I dont understand

```
 int x = *(int*)&M[index]
```

compared to

```
 int x = (int)M[index]
```

Can someone explain to me what is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the datatype of M is not int[], they may differ, take the case where you have an array of 2 (16 bit) shorts, 0x0123 and 0x4567. The memory layout (big endian) would/may be;

```
0x01 0x23 0x45 0x67
```

In the latter case with M[0], you'd assign the short correctly to the integer since you'd read M[0] and convert it to an integer, 0x00000123

In the first case you'd take the address of M[0] and *assume that what's in memory there is an integer*, that'd with a 32 bit integer type give the result 0x01234567 (ie all 4 bytes would be read)

Answer (score 1):

The former interprets the bytes of the memory at `&M[index]` as if an `int` is stored there and gives you that `int`.

The latter takes the numerical value of `M[index]` and converts it to an `int`.

If `M[index]` is of type `int`, there's no difference, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

The second one casts the value to an int, which means that it converts it in a meaningful way (and will cause an error if a cast is not possible), the first one grabs sizeof(int) bytes from a location in memory and represents them as an int, even though this may not make any sense.

For example:

```
double a[10];
a[5] = 281907.2389727;
int x = *(int*)&a[5];
int y = (int)a[5];
printf("%d %d", x, y);
```

Will output (on my machine/compiler):

```
-189447571 281907
```

Because the cast (int) will round down the double, while * (int * ) will pick up the first sizeof(int) bytes of the double, and "pretend" it's an integer - this of course doesn't give a meaningful result as they have different sizes and binary representations.

Answer (score 0):

What part is it that you don't understand?

The first expression is consists of two expressions: a pointer dereferencing, and an expression that evaluates into a pointer. `*(int *)` is the first part, it references the pointer that must follow, and `&M[index]` simply means "the address of the index:th element of the array M`.

In both your example, assuming `M` is an `int` array, the casts are completely unnecessary and should be removed. You could just as well use:

```
int x = *(&M[index]);
```

This form has the added benefit of making the two parts clearer; the first part is just the `*` operator outside the parenthesis, the second part is the code inside the parenthesis.

or

```
int x = M[index];
```

The latter form is the one to prefer, it's clear and to the point.

Comment: I'd guess as he was getting different results, his array is not an integer.